# How to return both failure status and failure reason from validate() method

Tags: java

I have a class whose purpose is storing some configuration parameters.

I need to add a method `validate()`, which checks the validity of the parameters of an object of this class at current state.

I need to return two information to the caller of `validate()` method

1. A `boolean` to indicate the validity
2. A `String` to provide the validation failure reason

What is the correct way to do this in java world?

I can think of several ways, but cannot identify which is better.

1. Return a string from `validate()`, which contains the failure
   reason, null if no error. It feels like this is a hack.
2. Throw an exception with failure reason if validate fails. This seems
   incorrect since validation failure is not an exceptional scenario
   for `validate()`
3. Create a class to hold validation status and failure reason and
   return an object of this. This looks like too much effort to such a
   simple requirement.

Comment: 4. Pass parameters by reference. Wouldn't recommend it, though.

Comment: Well, for example the response status in java rest api also has multiple fields. like status type, status info and so on. So I would choose the 3rd way.

Comment: are you using Spring? it has the exact functionality you are looking for

Comment: My `Configuration` class is an inner class and it is used only in the outer class. So I decided to go to 1st method with `validate()` renamed to `getValidationError()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to do this in java world?

There is no (single) correct way.

I agree that returning a `String` or `null` is ugly.

I disagree that creating a class is too much work.  Objectively, it should take you 5 minutes to write by hand, and 1 to 2 if you are using a decent IDE.  It is hard to argue that that is "too much".

It is debatable whether using exceptions for this is good style.  It depends on your views (or "religion") on exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

All three suggestions are ok. Which to choose depends very much on the context: team coding guidelines, company coding principles, team size, code size, ...

3) is the most elegant solution, I think. And the effort is not that huge...

1) is perfectly ok as long as it is documented well in JavaDoc, so that none of the callers is surprised. In JSE there are lots of examples of methods returning special values (null, -1, ...) the caller needs to check.

2) is more questionable. But if there is a project specific need for something like a `ValidationException` which could be used elsewhere in the code, it may be an acceptable way, as well. Probably worst performance of all variants, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on your program and *who* is the caller of `validate()` is. If you consider validation to be an internal implementation that has little visibility in the general flow of the program then Option 1 (which is very common) is simple and enough. Nevertheless, if the object holding parameters is public and `validate()` can be used generally across your program then Option 3 is what "Java" expects of you.

Option 2 is never better for the reason you said. Other argument is that is uses exceptions for control flow which makes the program harder to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following patterns:

- a "Validator" class that does the validation, and where you can get the reason;
- throwing an exception, the exception providing the reason;
- logging of the error with reason.